# Query same fields from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of different tables in a mySql database that all have the same structure.  Essentially every user gets its own table, which is set up identically to the other tables.  Is there a way to query all of these tables at once in php?  It is like I am trying to take 5 small tables and make one master table to display on a webpage.

Comment: No, there's no automatic way to do this. Why don't you just make it one master table for real, instead of splitting it up?

Comment: A separate table per user is usually poor design, precisely because of problems like this. It doesn't scale well to lots of users.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do it. Create a `UNION` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  union  all

```
select col1, col2, ... coln
from your_table1
union all 
select col1, col2, ... coln
from your_table2
union all 
select col1, col2, ... coln
from your_table3
union all 
.....
select col1, col2, ... coln
from your_tableN
```